# jenkins jacoco sonar integration

Tags: jenkins, jacoco

## I am facing an issue while configuring  Jacoco with sonar in Jenkins.

Currently I am creating a Jenkins job and my intention is to take an automatic build once I push code changes into git Hub. After that I need to take code coverage report and implemented using Jacoco with sonar.

### Sonarqube configuration in Jenkins(Works in localhost) is as follows

Sonarqube server is in localhost and port with 9000

### My Jenkins Home dir is as follows

Work space Root Dir: ${JENKINS_HOME}/workspace/${ITEM_FULLNAME}/

Then I created a new Job called Test123. Inside the Build option, I configured Maven,Sonar,Jacoco as follows

#### Maven Configuration

clean install

#### Sonar

[Sonar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6D0L.jpg)

#### Jacoco

[Jacoco](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TL41g.jpg)

### My Pom.xml

```
<build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.15</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>true</skip>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>unit-test</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <skip>${maven.test.skip}</skip>
                            <argLine>${argLine}</argLine>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>**/*IntegrationTest.java</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>integration-test</id>
                        <phase>integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <skip>${skipITs}</skip>
                            <argLine>${argLine}</argLine>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*IntegrationTest.java</include>
                            </includes>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.7.4.201502262128</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skip>${maven.test.skip}</skip>
                    <destFile>${basedir}/target/coverage-reports/jacoco-unit.exec</destFile>
                    <dataFile>${basedir}/target/coverage-reports/jacoco-unit.exec</dataFile>
                    <output>file</output>
                    <append>true</append>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>jacoco-initialize</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>jacoco-site</id>
                        <phase>verify</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>

    </build>
```

### Build Result is as follows

```
[JaCoCo plugin] Collecting JaCoCo coverage data...
[JaCoCo plugin] **/*.exec;**/*classes;**/src; locations are configured
[JaCoCo plugin] Number of found exec files for pattern **/*.exec: 1
[JaCoCo plugin] Saving matched execfiles:  C:\Users\pxp167\.jenkins\workspace\Test123\target\coverage-reports\jacoco-unit.exec
[JaCoCo plugin] Saving matched class directories for class-pattern: **/*classes:  C:\Users\pxp167\.jenkins\workspace\Test123\target\classes C:\Users\pxp167\.jenkins\workspace\Test123\target\test-classes
[JaCoCo plugin] Saving matched source directories for source-pattern: **/src:  C:\Users\pxp167\.jenkins\workspace\Test123\src
[JaCoCo plugin] Loading inclusions files..
[JaCoCo plugin] inclusions: [**/*.class]
[JaCoCo plugin] exclusions: [**/*Test*]
[JaCoCo plugin] Thresholds: JacocoHealthReportThresholds [minClass=0, maxClass=50, minMethod=0, maxMethod=50, minLine=0, maxLine=50, minBranch=0, maxBranch=50, minInstruction=0, maxInstruction=50, minComplexity=0, maxComplexity=50]
[JaCoCo plugin] Publishing the results..
[JaCoCo plugin] Loading packages..
[JaCoCo plugin] Done.
[JaCoCo plugin] Overall coverage: class: 0, method: 0, line: 0, branch: 0, instruction: 0
Build step 'Record JaCoCo coverage report' changed build result to UNSTABLE
Finished: UNSTABLE
```

### Could anyone please help me to correct my configuration

Answer (score 0):

Bit late but maybe helps others.
First at all you do not use test coverage by Sonar but by the "Jenkins JaCoCo plugin". Click at the question mark in Post Build Actions next to JaCoCo.

If your question is about the 0 test coverage, could be that no files are found. Check the classes and sources configuration you should have something in the logs that classes were found:

```
[JaCoCo plugin] Number of found exec files for pattern **/**.exec: 3
[JaCoCo plugin] Saving matched execfiles:  /srv/jenkins/workspace/eature_ContinousIntegration--api/build/jacoco/test.exec /srv/jenkins/workspace/-batch/build/jacoco/test.exec /srv/jenkins/workspace/-domain/build/jacoco/test.exec
[JaCoCo plugin] Saving matched class directories for class-pattern: **/classes: 
[JaCoCo plugin]  - /srv/jenkins/workspace/eature_ContinousIntegration-api/build/classes 8 files
[JaCoCo plugin]  - /srv/jenkins/workspace/-api/build/reports/tests/test/classes 0 files
```